# Capture website when using curl get content php

Tags: php, curl

I want get data from a website and capture a part content of website. Example: capture box menu of website.
See this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGEw8.png)

example

Comment: you have tried anything?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a request board. You have to try getting the job done by yourself instead of just asking people for solution.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a DOM-parser of sorts ([For example](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)) to read the entire structure of the website.

Be aware this is a very heavy process!

With a DOM parser you import the entire website structure, find the part you need and you can read the contents from it.